# apache spark streaming kafka integration error JAVA

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm working with spark streaming and kafka, i got this error.

Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream$$anonfun$start$1.apply(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream$$anonfun$start$1.apply(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:145)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:975)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:165)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:514)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
17/08/02 16:24:58 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext started

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

MY CODE :

```
     SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Streaming").setMaster("local");


       JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "exastax");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("loglar");
        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        streamingContext,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
        rdd.foreachPartition(consumerRecords -> {
            OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
            System.out.println(
                    o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());
        });
    });
        streamingContext.start();
        streamingContext.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

im using Kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0
I tried searching for this issue, but i can't find relevent jar.Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Scala 2.10 and Scala 2.11 code. Use either a Kafka-dependency with Scala 2.10, or Spark with Scala 2.11.

Comment: I do not understand where I need to organize..
Is it code or maven?

Comment: @TalhaK. this maven dep: `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` has to be `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10` like the other spark dependencies

Comment: Yes! it's run!! thnx a lot sir @maasg .But I can not write the values in Kafka.
stream.foreachRDD how to print values ?